# How to use special char like CODEA in CODE_128

Tags: c#, .net, zxing

I'm trying to make a barcode with ZXing but I'm not able to force it to use CODE_A Or CODE_B
I've tryed:

```
BarcodeWriter w = new BarcodeWriter();
w.Format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_128;
w.Options.GS1Format = false;
w.Options.Width = 1;
w.Options.Height = (int)(Heightmm * (g.DpiY / 25.4f));
Bitmap img = w.Write("0123456789");
```

Produces a CODE_C Barcode

Then star with CODE_A char (103) [(Acording to Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128) :

```
BarcodeWriter w = new BarcodeWriter();
w.Format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_128;
w.Options.GS1Format = false;
w.Options.Width = 1;
w.Options.Height = (int)(Heightmm * (g.DpiY / 25.4f));
Bitmap img = w.Write((char)103 +"0123456789");
```

But that only insert a "g" (in CODE_B) changes to CODE_C and inserts "0123456789"

I've also tryed using end Code A char (106)

```
BarcodeWriter w = new BarcodeWriter();
w.Format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_128;
w.Options.GS1Format = false;
w.Options.Width = 1;
w.Options.Height = (int)(Heightmm * (g.DpiY / 25.4f));
Bitmap img = w.Write((char)103 +"0123456789" + (char)106);
```

But this time the barcode produced only inserts a j at the end

What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: You can only try the following. Perhaps it is was your are looking for: `var writer = new BarcodeWriter { Options = new Code128EncodingOptions { ForceCodesetB = true }, Format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_128 };`

Answer (score 0):

You can't force ZXing.NET to switch Code Sets by putting the `Start Code A`, `Start Code B`, etc. codes in your input string. Instead, it will analyse your input string and automatically decide how to encode it based on the supported characters.

For more details, read the implementation of the `chooseCode` method [on GitHub](https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net/blob/afb7bb6aaff90030847e8040b071bb427ff58eee/Source/lib/oned/Code128Writer.cs#L273).